# Number of ways of distributing $6$ chocolates among $3$ children so that each child gets at least one of them

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Number of ways of distributing $6$ chocolates among $3$ children so that each child gets at least one of them

Now, question doesn't mentions whether chocolates are distinct or identical(children distinct of course)

Case 1: Chocolates identical:

so we're looking for number of positive integral solutions to the equation : $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6$ which is $C(5,2) = 10$

Case 2: Chocolates distinct:

here we're looking for onto function from a set $A$ of cardinality $6$ to set $B$ of cardinality $3$ = $S(6,3)$ $S$ is Stirling number of 2nd Kind.

Is this correct?

Comment: For the second:  With such small numbers, I think it is considerably simpler to just use inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stirling numbers are used to compute the number of nonempty subsets, without paying attention about the order of these subsets, not the number of surjections. In other ways - you treat children, as they're identical. I know it's Halloween and all children in captain America suit looks the same, but it's still not cool. Especially that you treat each chocolate separately.

To have your answer fully correct, you should multiply the number of nonempty divisions by the number of permutations of children.

Comment: not to mention the indistinct candy case is a slightly modified case of the third row of pascal's triangle 3,6,1 the 0 case is eliminated for the 3 remaining unforced candies, in both the all three get another, and 1 kid gets the rest cases; we only have one ordering. in the two kid case, we get two ordering of three pairs of kids.